# Nested regular expression for domain matching

Tags: regex, nested

Given the domain name `my.local.domain.com` I'd like to extract the following parts:

Match #1: `my.local.domain` ... excluding the top-level-domain (com)
Match #2: `local.domain` ... excluding the top-level-domain (com) and the first part (my)
Match #3: `domain` ... excluding the top-level-domain (com) and the two leading parts (my.local)

The regular expression does not have to match an unlimited amount of dot-separated parts, if the string gets longer, only the trailing 3 parts are relevant.

`my.local.domain.com`:
 #1: `my.local.domain`
 #2: `local.domain`
 #3: `domain`

`my.other.local.domain.com`
 #1: `my.other.local.domain`
 #2: `local.domain`
 #3: `domain`

If it's shorter this should match:

`domain.com`
 #1: `domain`
 #2: `domain`

So far this is my regular expression: `^(.+\.(.+\.(.+)?)?)\.com$`, the problem is that as soon as the domain has less than 4 dot-separated parts, it doesn't work anymore. I'm struggling with getting the inner brackets optional.

Any hint on this? Thanks a lot!

Comment: have you tried to replace `+` by `*` for the optional components?

Comment: Yes. Problem also that the dots (`\.`) should be optional in between, but if I rearrange the regular expression in any way it just gets worse. That's the closest I could get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It gets a bit complicated thanks to the optionality restrains, but following works on your examples:

```
((?:\w+\.)*?(\w*?\.?(\w+)))\.com$
```

See technical explanation of all operators on http://regex101.com/r/aJ6bZ0/1

Logic is as follows:

1. `(\w+)\.com$` matches the domain
2. `(\w*\.?(...))` will optionally match the preceding subdomain
3. `(?:\w+\.)*` will optionally match all preceding sub-subdomains
4. `*?` instead of `*` will force the operator to be lazy - it begins by not matching any character, so giving a chance to the greedy `\w+` from 1st step to match the whole domain if there are no subdomains

Comment: Uh oh, I think that's it. :) Thanks a lot! Was pulling my hair on this.

Comment: The combo `*?` baffles me. Does it mean `0 or more and optional`?

Comment: just added some explanation - you can try to replace `*?` by `*` and `+` by `+?` to experiment with the effects of lazy vs. greedy operators..

Answer (score 1):

The '+' regex symbol can be thought of as "one or more times".  You would want to use either '*' - 0 or more times or '?' - 0 or 1 time.  This goes for your literal '.' as well, which should happen ? or 0 or more times based on your explanation above.

See [this google search](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=regex%20cheat%20sheet) for a huge list of handy references to help further. (They all say mostly the same thing, but it's nice to have options)

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I'm aware of the + and * pattern symbols, still I wasn't able to modify the regular expression to get the desired result.

Comment: the crucial distinction is between greedy and lazy operators, not between `+` and `*` in this particular case..